# readlink retorna sólo 6 salidas a un archivo

Tags: linux, bash

veréis, tengo un problema un tanto raro. Estoy trabajando con readlink para obtener los archivos de la forma `f*.jpg`. El tema es que esta búsqueda la hago en una serie de carpetas (muchas) que tienen el mismo formato `nombre.número`.

Para hacer la búsqueda en todas las carpetas utlizo un bucle for

```
for (( i=1; i<226; i++ )); do readlink -e ./recup_dir.$i/f*.jpg; done
```

Cuando ejecuto esto la salida es perfecta, entra en todos los directorios y hace la búsqueda de los jpg perfectamente.

**El problema** viene cuando necesito sacar esa salida a un archivo

```
for (( i=1; i<226; i++ )); do readlink -e ./recup_dir.$i/f*.jpg > /home/kali/nombres; done
```

En este caso solo aparecen 6 direcciones en el archivo. Sé que el comando `readlink` con el `for` funciona bien porque se ve en la salida de la terminal todas las rutas perfectamente (salen alrededor de 40000 rutas, hay muchísimos archivos entre todas las carpetas); pero en cambio cuando meto el `>`para llevar al salida al archivo sólo devuelve las 6 últimas rutas

¿Qué puede pasar?, porque el `readlink` va bien, y está devolviendo una salida al texto, pero no sé porqué sólo salen 6

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo está funcionando exactamente como tu esperas. Tu `for( )` hace lo que tiene que hacer, y tu `readlink` también hace lo que tiene que hacer.

¿ Cual es el problema ? Pues muy sencillo: cada `readlink ...` es una orden individual en si misma. Y, como orden individual, hace exactamente lo que tiene que hacer: **reescribir el archivo** `/home/kali/nombres` con el resultado de su ejecución.

Por lo tanto, tu bucle ejecuta `readlink` 225 veces, y cada una de esas veces intenta crear un archivo nuevo. Como el archivo ya existe, simplemente lo reescribe, perdiendo el contenido anterior.

Simplemente, no sobre-escribas: **Añade** al archivo:

```
for (( i=1; i<226; i++ )); do
    readlink -e ./recup_dir.$i/f*.jpg >> /home/kali/nombres;
done
```

Comment: Si, exactamente era eso. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

@Trauma ya contestó tu pregunta, pero recuerdo que se puede hacer algo por el estilo. Ando oxidado en Bash y no recuerdo exactamente la razón del por qué:

```
for (( i=1; i<226; i++ )); do
    readlink -e ./recup_dir.$i/f*.jpg
done > /home/kali/nombres
```

Y los archivos no se sobreescriben una y otra vez en cada `readlink ...`.

De esta manera **no estás abriendo y cerrando en cada entrada** tu archivo `/home/kali/nombres` para escritura.